# mfc when to use logical/device coordinates

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have heard that rectangles, coordinates of the mouse and other things involving drawing all use device coordinates. Is this true? Are there any ways that can tell me if I have logical or device coordinates?

I could look at the documentation of functions that give me the coordinates, but sometimes they don't explicitly say if these are logical or device coordinates. For example, the documentation for [`GetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx) function says it "retrieves the position of the mouse cursor, in screen coordinates."

I am assuming screen coordinates are the same as device coordinates? Does this mean I have to convert the screen coordinates I get from the function into client coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You know what coordinate `(0,0)` is on the top-left corner of screen. But on paper when we draw a graph, `(0,0)` may be on bottom left, or on the centre of the graph plotting paper.

By default, the logical and coordinates and physical/screen coordinates are same, and (0,0) points to top-left. But what if you want to draw a line from bottom left to somewhere in middle of screen, that matches the math/trigonometry you've learnt or are practising? Well, the you move to changing the logical coordinate system to something of your liking.

You'd use [SetMapMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162980(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the logical coordinate system. You may later use `LPtoDP`, `DPtoLP`, `ClientToScreen`, `ScreenToClient` etc for mapping and for physical monitor to your window coordinates mapping.

[About Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162466(v=vs.85).aspx)